# Rspec multiple spec folders

Tags: ruby, rspec

Im currently building a project using Rspec in which I sepparated in two different folders with domain code and infrastructure code. Both folders have their own specs in a spec folder. The domain/spec folder is the one containing the spec_helper.rb file, thats required from the tests inside the other folder infrastructure/spec

I'd like to know how to have a spec folder in the root of the project, including the spec_helper file and also tests, and being able to run all the tests with just one command (right now I do it running rspec domain/ infrastructure/)

Comment: Instead of _domain/spec_ and _infrastructure/spec_, can you do _spec/domain_ and _spec/infrastructure_ and keep _spec_helper.rb_ directly under _/spec_, and run all the rspecs with `rspec spec/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RSpec` is designed to work with all tests in *one* folder. By default, this folder is called `spec/`, but you can [use a different name](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/setting-the-default-spec-path) with the `--default-path` option.

So, your options as I see it are:

1. Edit the [source code](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb#L1027-L1037) of `rspec-core` to let that configuration support multiple directories. Hopefully your PR will be approved and merged.
2. Or, write a simple wrapper script that runs `rspec` against both directories. For example, you could `alias rspecs='rspec domain/ infrastructure/'`.
3. Or (*what I would recommend!*), you could just restructure your tests slightly to use `spec/domain/` and `spec/infrastructure/` folders -- and then everything will just work, by convention, out of the box.

Comment: Another point to note - choosing option 3 will be less confusing for *other developers* who look at your code! Ruby developers will be expecting to see all tests in one folder named `test/` or `spec/`, *not* in two folders named `domain/` and `infrastructure/`.

Comment: I also recommend option 3!

Comment: How to configure the rails generator to customize these new directories, i.e.: `rails g rspec:integration <test_case>` to create the file at `./spec/integrations/test_case_spec.rb`?

Comment: @leompeters Could you please post that as a new question, rather than here as a comment?