# How to configure RSpec to find specs in alternate folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here's my code layout -- it's basically two separate rails apps that are being piece-wise refactored into a common code base:

```
app1/
  app/
  lib/
  spec/
    models/
    controllers/
    lib/
app2/
  app/
  lib/
  spec/
    models/
    controllers/
    lib/
common/
  lib/
  spec/
```

Both of the apps get build into docker containers, with the `common/` part mounted under the root, so in the runtime env, it looks like this:

```
root/
  app/
  common/
    lib/
    spec/
  lib/
  spec/
    models/
    controllers/
    lib/
```

I know I can do `rspec common/spec` to run the specs in the `common/spec` folder, but is there a way to configure rspec so that just running `rspec` will run the specs in both `spec/` and `common/spec`?

Comment: Have you tried `--default-path` option? https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/configuration/setting-the-default-spec-path

Comment: The `--default-path` option is only a single path. I want rspec to load spec files from *both* `spec/` and `common/spec/`. `--default-path` does not make that work.

In theory, I could use `--default-path=.` but that would be super janky, probably cause a host of other issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rspec multiple spec folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51648304/rspec-multiple-spec-folders)